# Angular 4 - How to parse hyphened variable in template for Karma testing?

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-template, angular-test

I am facing an issue while unit testing my Angular 4 component with Karma. Below is the command I am running to test:

```
tsc && karma start --browsers PhantomJS
```

I have hyphened variable as below, which is bound with the HTML template and I verified the bind is working and data displays on the page (in browser).

**Hyphned variable - in a component.ts file**

```
template-variable-key
```

But during the unit testing, I am facing an issue as it gives below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'layout-permission-title-key' of undefined
```

---

#### How I defined in HTML template

**(1)** In template with EXPRESSION

```
<p>{{error['template-variable-key']}}</p>
```

**(2)** OR In template with data binding using `innerHtml`

```
<p [innerHtml]="error['template-variable-key']"></p> <!-- or -->

<p [innerHtml]="error?.template-variable-key"></p>
```

**Note:** As the same hyphened variable is being used at many places other than Angular, I cannot change it to camelCase or something else.

**(1)** and **(2)** both didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can try is but an *ngIf="error" on anywhere that tries to use the error property

```
<p *ngIf="error" [innerHtml]="error['template-variable-key']"></p>
```

The binding is looking for a property called error and that is undefined so when it tries to access template-variable-key you get the undefined error.

You need to mock the error object on you component.

Usually your spec files you have a section like have a section like this in your spec file

```
let component: YourComponentType;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponentType>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ YourComponentType ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponentType);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

In the second before each you can mock the error object with

```
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.error = { };
component.error['template-variable-key'] = 'Your test data';
```

Or in your component just have a default for the error object with

```
error = {};
```

Comment: I already tried this but giving error as mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: You have tried the bit where you just have a default object for the error property? That should stop it from being undefined. Show the TypeScript for your component, you might have a service that assigns undefined to the error property during the execution of the test.

Comment: I doubt the problem lies in hyphenated property names, the error suggests that you are trying to access properties on a property that is undefined. But the safe navigation operator error?.template-variable-key is not valid.

Comment: Service has the response coming and mentioned in the description above, i could see the same in browser. So undefined is not the case here @Adrian.

Comment: Did you try my edit with the ngIf on the element with the error?